# What it means ''depth()'' in java?

Tags: java

I am in a book with this code.  I do not know which command the ''depth'' word is used for  what purpose. I have found a few results but I do not understand what is still. I know java language but i am learning c ++ new.I wanted to know if there is something like this in Java.

```
if (depth() != otherStack.depth()) 
{ 
      return false; 
}
else 
{ 
for (int n=0; n<depth(); n++) 
{ 
if (!list[n].equals(otherStack.list[n])) 
     return false; 
} 
}
```

Comment: Your question is about Java, _not_ JavaScript and _not_ C++.

Comment: Please give more info. What book are you reading? Is the code in your question C++ or Java.

Comment: Data Structures Using C++ is book name. I'm not sure exactly C++ or Java. Because the  Book occasionally given java examples. But I have never encountered any depth in Java before. That's why, I thought it was c ++ code, the main language of the book.

Answer (score 3):

From the code snippet you posted, depth seems to be a method defined in the class whose instance is the `otherStack` variable. Here depth() probably returns the size of the stack.
The line `depth() != otherStack.depth()` compares the size of the Stack instance to the size of another Stack instance.